Add typed HttpClient gets stuck
Whenever I try to add typed HttpClient to my application, it goes into an infinite loop until I run out of memory, or I kill the process.
I am using it as follows:
services.AddHttpClient<IHandler, HandlerImplementation>(opt =>
{
    opt.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("endpoints")["remoteService"] ?? string.Empty);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthenticationDelegatingHandler>();

and the handler looks as follows
public class HandlerImplementation : AbstractHandler, IHandler
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient

    public HandlerImplementation(HttpClient client, IBaseDependency dependency) : base(dependency)
    {
        _httpClient = client;
    }
}

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

What's the stack trace when this "infinite loop" happens? My guess would be you have a circular dependency in your DI configuration that's causing a StackOverflowException.

Probably you're using IHandler in a Singleton service?!
